# How can I get the general term of this recurrence equations?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion, integer-sequence

Following is the recurrence relation:

```
a[1] = 1;
a[n_] := a[n - a[n - 1]] + 1
Array[a, 28]
```

I tried to use `RSolve`, but it doesn't gives a correct answer.

```
Clear[a]
RSolve[{a[n] == a[n - a[n - 1]] + 1}, a[n], a]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I believe your `RSolve` syntax is incorrect.  I think you want `n` as the last argument, and you should also have the `a[1] == 1` rule:

```
RSolve[{a[n] == a[n - a[n - 1]] + 1, a[1] == 1}, a[n], n]
```

This gives a more informative (error?) message:

> RSolve::nestdv: The expression a[-1+n] has nested dependent variables. >>

Apparently `RSolve` doesn't like that.

Second, your recursive function is very inefficient because it lacks [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html).  Adding that will make it more practical:

```
a[1] = 1;
a[n_] := a[n] = a[n - a[n - 1]] + 1

Array[a, 500000] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 1.529
> ```

Finally, we can work out a function for the nth term manually.  Observe that in your sequence each number n repeats n times:

> 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, ...

The jump points are therefore [triangular numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangularNumber.html):

```
# (# + 1)/2 & ~Array~ 5
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 6, 10, 15}
> ```

We can invert this equation with `Solve`:

```
Solve[n (n + 1)/2 == x, n]
```

> ```
> {{n -> 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[1 + 8 x])}, {n -> 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 x])}}
> ```

Then pick the correct branch and add `Ceiling`:

```
fn[x_] := Ceiling[ (Sqrt[1 + 8 x] - 1)/2 ]
```

Now:

```
fn ~Array~ 15
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}
> ```

Comment: Warning : in `Mathematica 8` and later `Solve[1/2 n (1 + n) == k, n, Integers]` yields the result in terms of `ConditionalExpression`. You should rather use simply `Solve[1/2 n (1 + n) == k, n]`. +1.

Comment: @Artes Thanks for the correction.